# Spring WebFlux how to get objects from two flatMap's

Tags: spring-webflux

I am sure this has been already asked but I can't really describe it and search for it. I hope it gets clear what I try to accomplish from the following code:

```
userRepository.findAll()
  .flatMap(u -> commentRepository.findByUser(u.getId))
  .flatMap( // here i get of course the comment object but i also need the previous user object )
```

Comment: Hey did you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the second `flatMap` internally with the `commentRepository.findByUser(u.getId)` and then perform the desired operation inside that internal `flatMap`

This will look like :

```
 userRepository.findAll()
            .flatMap(u -> commentRepository.findByUser(u.getId).flatMap(comment -> {
              // operation on comment
              // operation on u
              // return result 
            }));
```

You may also want to return the final result of the whole chain above, in order to maintain the chaining.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use zip, so in next flatMap you will get tupple with item from findAll and then findUser.

```
  userRepository.findAll()
      .flatMap(u -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(u), commentRepository.findByUser(u.getId)))
      .flatMap(tuple-> tuple.getT1() || tuple.getT2()  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
userRepository.findAll()
  .flatMap(u -> {
    List<Comment> commentsByUserId = commentRepository.findByUser(u.getId);
    commentsByUserId.flatMap(// rest of the code)
    // code
})
```